# LXD ubuntu image startup issue: snap.lxd.activate.service not found

Tags: 22.04, snap, lxc, lxd

I am new to LXC/LXD and would like to start using it, but I have encountered an issue while launching a new ubuntu 22.04 image.

I have installed lxd using snap, following the instructions given on the [LXD install page](https://ubuntu.com/lxd/install).

```
lxc launch ubuntu:22.04 test
lxc shell test
```

The `snapd.seed.service` systemd job never finishes. Checking the systemd jobs within the container gives:

```bash
root@test:~# systemctl list-jobs
JOB UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
2   multi-user.target                    start waiting
136 cloud-config.service                 start waiting
145 ubuntu-advantage.service             start waiting
1   graphical.target                     start waiting
127 snapd.autoimport.service             start waiting
113 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
116 snapd.seeded.service                 start running
135 cloud-init.target                    start waiting
142 cloud-final.service                  start waiting

9 jobs listed.
```

```bash
root@test:~# systemctl status snapd.seeded.service
● snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2023-08-29 14:08:49 UTC; 18min ago
   Main PID: 428 (snap)
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 17608)
     Memory: 21.5M
        CPU: 2.060s
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.seeded.service
             └─428 /usr/bin/snap wait system seed.loaded

Aug 29 14:08:49 test systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
```

```bash
root@test:~# systemctl status snap.lxd.activate.service
× snap.lxd.activate.service
     Loaded: not-found (Reason: Unit snap.lxd.activate.service not found.)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-08-29 14:24:14 UTC; 5min ago
   Main PID: 4450 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 27ms

Aug 29 14:24:14 test systemd[1]: Starting Service for snap application lxd.activate...
Aug 29 14:24:14 test systemd[1]: snap.lxd.activate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 29 14:24:14 test systemd[1]: snap.lxd.activate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 14:24:14 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application lxd.activate.
```

```bash
root@test:~# journalctl -xe
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit snapd.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 11.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit snapd.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit snapd.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit snapd.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3052 and the job result is done.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: snapd.service: Consumed 7.198s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit snapd.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snapd.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit snapd.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3052.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: overlord.go:268: Acquiring state lock file
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: overlord.go:273: Acquired state lock file
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 1...
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 2...
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 3...
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: daemon.go:247: started snapd/2.58+22.04.1 (series 16; classic; devmode) ubuntu/22.04 (amd64) linux/6.4.6-76060406-generic.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d2772350938.mount: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d2772350938.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: daemon.go:340: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: backends.go:58: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled but some kernel features are missing: dbus, network
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snapd.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit snapd.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3052.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: snap-snapd-19993.mount: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit snap-snapd-19993.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: snap-snapd-19993.mount: Unit process 110 (snapfuse) remains running after unit stopped.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: snap-snapd-19993.mount: Consumed 1.627s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit snap-snapd-19993.mount completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug 29 14:34:32 test snapd[7253]: handlers.go:662: Reported install problem for "snapd" as already-reported
```

I would appreciate any help in finding the problem and resolving it (and learning more about LXC/LXD along the way).

Comment: We're seeing the same issue here. I've created a thread about this in the Canonical Discourse but haven't received any replies yet: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-and-20-04-containers-stuck-in-system-is-booting-up-state/39470

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "solution", but what we've seen affecting this is the `snapd` package, as indicated above. *For some reason*, the `snapd.seed.service` never finishes. `apt-get purge snapd` and then `apt-get install snapd` (if you need/want it installed) seems to workaround the issue, somehow.

The problem seems to be related to these pre-seeded snaps:

```yaml
snaps:
  -
    name: core20
    channel: stable
    file: core20_2015.snap
  -
    name: snapd
    channel: stable
    file: snapd_20092.snap
  -
    name: lxd
    channel: 5.0/stable/ubuntu-22.04
    file: lxd_24322.snap
```

This list of pre-seeded snaps seems to be "burned into" the image, so to speak. On a machine where the `ubuntu:22.04` image works, it means these snaps are available by default:

```
root@hip-weasel:~# snap list
Name    Version        Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core20  20230801       2015   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
lxd     5.0.2-838e1b2  24322  5.0/stable/…   canonical✓  -
snapd   2.60.3         20092  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

#### Workaround

When you do `apt-get purge snapd` and `apt-get install snapd`, these snaps are **not** pre-seeded any more. So that's why it "works". But it would sure be interesting to understand more about *why* this happens and *why only on some of our machines*...

```
root@settling-monster:/var/lib/snapd# snap list
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
```

Comment: This is a few years old, but seems similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1878225